# Does Google Photos have Reverse image search?

Tags: google-photos, google-image-search

Google Images has Reverse image search, whereas I can use a picture as my search to find related images from around the web.

Does Google Photos have Reverse image search whereas I can use a picture as my search to find related images within my photos?

Comment: That would be a nifty feature!

Answer (score 1):

in theory its possible. first you would need to share whole folder with all pictures with public

- go to **https://photos.google.com/**
- sign in to your Google Account
- place your cursor over a photo or folder and click **Select ✔**
- click **Share** [image] and select **Public**
- get your shared link
- go to **https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi**
- perform your search
- and then add **site:YOUR-SHARED-LINK** into search box

[image]